# How can I back to previous page using angular tab in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to go back to the previous page when the user clicks the back button but my current code didnt do anything means the page is not redirecting my current code is give below

```
<a href="#" onClick="goBack();" <i class="icon-white icon-chevron-left"></i></a>


function goBack()
{
  window.location.href =document.referrer;

}
```

any thoughts????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Your JavaScript may not be loading before your HTML is.

Another thing: it is considered 'bad practice' to tie JavaScript functions to HTML elements. You could try, instead:

**HTML**

```
<a id="goBackLink" href='#'>...</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#goBackLink').click(function() {
    window.location.href = document.referrer;
}
```

Of course, this means using the jQuery library. If you don't want to use the jQuery library your function would instead look like:

```
document.getElementById('goBackLink').onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = document.referrer;
}
```

Which I think should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage session history management:

```
 window.history.back()
```

Note that this is supported in all major browsers, except IE 9 and below.